# Set variable with if in javascript function

Tags: javascript

This does not loop... How do I set variable with an if function like I have attempted to do(i am very new to javascript)

```js
noStroke();
var x = 10;
    
draw = function() {
    background(151, 244, 247)
    fill(255, 0, 115);
    rect(x, 200, 100, 20);
    rect(x + 15, 178, 70, 40);
    fill(77, 66, 66);
    ellipse(x + 25, 221, 24, 24);
    ellipse(x + 75, 221, 24, 24);
    
    x = x + 1;
};
var func = function() { if (x>300){set x = 1}};
```

I have googled how to set variable with function in this manner, but cannot find anything on it... Don't be the guy who says ¨ever heard of google?¨
this is the start of a busy highway background on a website

Comment: `set x = 1` isn’t valid syntax. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Where do you call func() ?? and it should just be `x = 1`

Comment: Please consider reading the [JavaSript tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).  It has a section about learning JavaScript and considering the syntax in your question, you need to review the constructs of the language.  Your program is invalid in many ways and you haven't really provided a MVCE.

Comment: Gforce I am trying to make x reset itself, and therefore loop the moving car

Comment: Wish I could delete this question...

Comment: You should be able to.  None of the answers to your question have upvotes.

Comment: it says people have invested work into making answers so I can't

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a nicer way to write it, with the invalid `set` keyword removed:

```
var x = 100;

// do something ..

var func = function() {
    if (x > 300) {
        x = 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The following demonstrates how to set the value of a variable using an `if` statement.

```js
var x = 10;

if (x > 5) {
  x = 1000;
}

console.log(x);
```

Referencing the code you've provided in your post, you are running into a couple of problems. To begin, `set` is an invalid keyword and can be removed. Next, you initially set the value of `x` to 10, then in your `draw()` function, you have `x = x + 1`, which will increment that initial value, but you never call this function, nor do you call `func()`. Please provide a full code sample so that we can assist you further.

Answer (score -2):

The question is somewhat unclear, but below code should demonstrate how to use if condition
and function to return/assign a value to variable.

```
addsTo2 = (n1, n2) => {
    return n1 + n2 === 2 ? `yes, ${n1} + ${n2} is 2`: `no, ${n1} + ${n2} is ${n1 + n2} instead`;
}
result = addsTo2(1,1)
// outputs > "yes, 1 + 1 is 2"
result = addsTo2(1,3)
// outputs > "no, 1 + 3 is 4 instead"
```

If you want to assign a variable in a loop, contantly incrementing it then use 
for loop.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('drawing i', i);
}
```

Comment: 8 minutes isn't "a while"

If you write a post and dont refresh the page every few minutes then ... more than 1 person can write an answer at the same time. Also, the answer shows a different way of doing the same thing(ternary operator)